# Tomcat-Https Post-File Upload-Parameters become null

Tags: java, tomcat, post

I am trying to create a simple https service which allows an end user to upload a file to my system. I am using the HttpRequester plugin in firefox to test this service.

My code seems to work (file data reaches the server) when the files I am uploading are less than 1MB in size but does not work (`request.getParameter(file)` returns null) when the file size is larger than 1 MB.

After some googling around I changed some parameters in server.xml

```
<Connector port="21003"  maxPostSize="0" maxHttpHeaderSize="0"/>
```

But still no luck.

Any idea of what I could try next? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you share your upload servlet code and full connector settings?

Comment: I am using httpRequester to send the data. Here is a snapshot of my request                                                                                            POST https://server_name:port_number/app_name/uploadFile
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
fileuploadtype=machine&filename=I01&type=machine&sessionIdentifier=123456&Content-Length=2646478&file=ICAgIDEgU1FMIEVycm9yK.. [Rest of the data]